# How to add channel security as https in spring security using "annotations"?

Tags: java, spring, security, spring-mvc, spring-security

I am using annotations in my application for spring and spring security. As I am not using xml configuration files for spring security, I am not able to use below code:

```
<intercept-url pattern="/secure/**" access="ROLE_ADMIN" requires-channel="https"/>
```

I want an alternative for above code in annotation based configuration, but even after searching a lot, was not able to get any luck.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That code was part of spring security config. You need to create a class and extend **WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter**. Part of the code above is same as:

```
.antMatchers("/secure/**").access("hasRole('ADMIN')")
.requiresChannel().anyRequest().requiresSecure()
```

In addition, you can refer to `@PreAuthorize("hasRole('ROLE_ADMIN')")` as one of annotation method.